# SQL Server Reporting Services Default Values From Query not working in deployed report

Tags: reporting-services

In order to populate a textbox in a page header I am setting up a parameter (as you cannot use Fields) and referencing this in the textbox. The parameter has the Default Value set to "From Query" and the Dataset and Value Field are set accordingly. This works a treat in developmentt in Visual Studio 2005. Once I have deployed the report and am viewing the report in the ReportViewer control I get the error:

"Parameter validation failed. It is not possible to provide valid values for all parameters. (rsParameterError)".

If I remove the parameter, the report works fine.

(Strange thing is that I thought I had this working earlier).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've probably checked, but has the default value copied over? I've had issues in the past with reporting services where the default values were lost when I moved a report from one box to another.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the answer - it has pointed me in the right direction...I have been using my own program to deploy multiple reports so rarely look at them via the Report Manager website. Anyway - I just deployed the report on my home PC and it worked fine....looking at the report in Report Manager on both PCs I found that "Prompt User" on the PC that wasn't working was not ticked...go figure. Ticking this resolved the problem.

I am liking the results that I am getting from SSRS, but I am quite new to it and am finding some things (like this) a little frustating...mouse and keyboard are lucky to not find themselves thrown out the window!

Comment: I had this issue too.  I resolved it by providing an expression, like: ="1"